# How can I show that this recursive sequence is monotonic and converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

can someone help me show that this recursive sequence, is bounded and monotonic, and thus converges? Cant seem to get my head around this,  maybe this would work through induction, but im not sure what to start that with.

Let $x_1>0$ and $$x_{n+1}:=\frac{2x_n}{1+x_n^2}\quad \quad n\in\mathbb N.$$

Comment: haha thanks, wasn´t sure about that

Comment: Consider when $0<x_1<1$ and $1\leqslant x_1<\infty$.

Comment: Well I guess I want to prove that 1 is the upper bound for Xn first ? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

We can get started by thinking about monotonicity first. A sequence is monotone when

$x_{n+1} - x_n \leq 0$ or $x_{n+1} - x_n \geq 0.$ We've got an equation for $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n,$ and clearly when $x_{n+1} = x_n$ is a break point between the increasing and decreasing cases, so let's play with that (setting $x = x_n$):

$$x_{n+1} - x = 0 \implies \frac {2x} {1 + x^2} = x$$

or $x = 1.$ This motivates the hint by Math1000. A little more fiddling around will tell you that we get an increasing function when $x_n < 1$ and a decreasing function when $x_n > 1.$

So you should start by showing an upper bound for when $x_n < 1$ and a lower bound for when $x_n > 1.$ This will end up finishing the proof, since it will also show that $x_n$ can't jump from increasing to decreasing.